# How to explode a string without proper delimiter - PHP

Tags: php, explode, substr

I'm doing a custom page for my WP website and for this I'm getting the content of an existing WP page. Getting the content is not a problem but I'm getting it like this :

```
https://youtu.be/abcdefghijkhttps://youtu.be/kjihgfedcbahttps://youtu.be/abcdefghijk
```

I'd like to transform it like this :

```
https://youtu.be/abcdefghijk
https://youtu.be/kjihgfedcba
https://youtu.be/abcdefghijk
```

I tried `explode('/', $content)` but it's not working as I want.
I don't know if I can use `substr()` in this case.

How can I do to separate each url properly or atleast separate each video's id ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all video id(s) as an array like this:

```
$str = "https://youtu.be/abcdefghijkhttps://youtu.be/kjihgfedcbahttps://youtu.be/abcdefghijk";
$videos = explode("https://youtu.be/",$str);
```

If you `print_r($videos);` you will see all the id in an array.

If you want these array values as full URLs, then do like this:

```
$videos = array_map(function($value) { return ' '.$value; }, $videos);
```

Comment: When I see your answer, which is perfect, I'm thinking that I'm a bit dumb sometimes. Thank you !

Comment: You can oneline reconstruct this as well using `array_map(function ($v) { return "https://youtu.be/$v"; }, explode("https://youtu.be/", $str))`

Comment: I'd like to accept it but I can't, I need to wait 10min.

Comment: It would be faster, and clearer to understand to put the full URLs like this instead of with array_map :) `foreach ($videos as $key => $value) { $videos[$k] = 'https://youtu.be/'.$value; }`